# React native java.lang.string cannot be cast to java.lang.double

Tags: react-native

I have been trying to animate error icon in react native . If error is false,icon appears in a proper way(with no animation),but if error is true then I get this error(it is the case that I want to animate) java.lang.string cannot be cast to java.lang.double. I am using react-native-animatable library. Any help will help me,thanks.

```
    //in text input
    <Error error={error ? true : false}>
      <RoundedIcon size={widthPercentageToDP("4%")} name={error ? "x" : "check"} color="white" backgroundColor={error ? "danger" : "primary"} />
    </Error>
                
 // error component
    import * as Animatable from "react-native-animatable";
        type ErrorProps = {
          children: ReactNode;
          error?: boolean;
        };
        
       
        export const Error = ({ children, error = false, ...props }: ErrorProps) => {
          const element = useRef(null);
        
          useEffect(() => {
            if (error) {
              element.current.animate("shake", 500, "linear");
            }
          }, [error]);
        
          return <Animatable.View ref={element}>{children}</Animatable.View>;
        };
```